# Excel Automation Windows Service

Tags: c#, excel, windows-services, office-interop, excel-interop

I have a Windows Service that runs the `Excel Interop` in order to automate the execution of various macros. However, I am running in a peculiar issue when I try to *run a macro which access a database using Windows Authentication*...

If the macro is run **through the Windows Service**, the workbook is opened and the macro is execution is started but the application hangs (presumably at the data access portion).

If, however, the macro is run **through the Visual Studio debugger**, using the same implementation as the service (they call the same class library), it executes, saves the workbook, and closes as expected.

I'm sure this has something to do with impersonation, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have the windows service running under my user and I have also modified the default COM properties in the Component Services to `Impersonate` instead of the default `Identify`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as it would be preferred to run as a windows service and not a console application.

Comment: Yes, [Office from a Windows Service can be tricky](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us)...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I'm a bit late, but here I go anyway:

I had a similar issue and solved it by creating a `Desktop` folder in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile` and `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`.

It seems that Excel is not able to run under a specific user when used in a Windows service. Therefore, it runs with the LocalSystem service account, and it requires a Desktop folder in order to interact with Excel interop.

I have no further explanation, but it worked for me and it didn't cause any other know issue. I searched quite a lot for a definitive answer, but everything I found described the solution without specifying a reason.

Comment: Yeah that's already set up. I had to do that to get it to work at all. The problem I'm having is specific to when it attempts to query a database using a trusted connection within a macro. Thanks though.