# How to get a Windows Service VB.net to access an excel macro

Tags: vb.net, excel, windows-services, vba

I have looked at a few stackoverflow articles
[Excel Automation Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349386/excel-automation-windows-service)
and 
[How to run excel vba code from a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054332/how-to-run-an-excel-macro-from-a-windows-service)

So the answer seems like it can't be done.

I have an xlsm file (Microsoft Excel Macro-Enabled Worksheet) that has one macro in it.  It simply opens a .csv file, look loops through it, and outputs a excel file.

I have 5 or 6 of these (each one processes the csv file differently for each client) that when we had 1-2 wasn't a problem to manually run the process to get the Excel output.  I would like to simply automate this process.  I currently have a service, the one that produces the csv, that seems like the best spot to do this.

The service runs on a server, the service looks at a database and sees if a csv (or other report) needs to be produced.

So has anything changed, can I to excel automation in a service now?  How?  If not Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

My personal suggestion would to do everything that the macros do directly in the service. For instructions on interacting with Excel files from VB.Net see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302094.