# Interop.Excel library not working in WindowsService

Tags: c#, excel, windows-services, interop

On Website using ASP.Net in visual studio, I succeed to send an email with xls file. But when I copy this code, it does not work in windowsService. When I debug, they don't have any errors and the program just hang on before

```
Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

this part.

Runs with the LocalSystem, and I already try making this folder.

```
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

 C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

But still hang on.
This is the code.

```
     private void Email()
    {
        //get the data from database
        DataTable data = GetData();
        DataTable email_data = GetEmailData();

        this.WriteToFile("78");  
        // Create an Excel object and add workbook...


      ////////////program stops here
        Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(false); // true for object template???

        this.WriteToFile("7");
        // Global missing reference for objects we are not defining...
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        this.WriteToFile("77");
        // Add column headings...
        int iCol = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn c in data.Columns)
        {
            iCol++;
            excel.Cells[1, iCol] = c.ColumnName;
        }
        // for each row of data...
        int iRow = 0;
        foreach (DataRow r in data.Rows)
        {
            iRow++;

            // add each row's cell data...
            iCol = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn c in data.Columns)
            {
                iCol++;
                excel.Cells[iRow + 1, iCol] = r[c.ColumnName];
            }
        }



        // If wanting to Save the workbook...
        this.WriteToFile("1");


        workbook.SaveAs(@"C:\Windows\temp\NSOList.xls",
        Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, missing, missing,
        false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
        missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

        this.WriteToFile("2");
        workbook.Close();

        using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
        {
            this.WriteToFile("3");
            mm.From = new MailAddress("aa@gmail.com");

            for (int i = 0; i < email_data.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                mm.Bcc.Add(email_data.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            }
            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {

                mm.Subject = "List";

                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"C:\Windows\temp\List.xls"));
                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                credentials.UserName = "aa@gmail.com";
                credentials.Password = "1234";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = credentials;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                this.WriteToFile("4");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                smtp.Send(mm);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349386/excel-automation-windows-service

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but you definitly should use another approach inside a webapplication to generate an excel file (google for openxml sdk)... or at least correctly free the used memory with Marshal.ReleaseComObject...

Comment: Have you checked if there is an error message in Event Log?
My first guess would be that the account the service is logging in with does not have permission to write to windows temp.
Also, if possible you should try to avoid having to write the file to disk and keep it in memory. And if that's not possible, you should avoid hardcoding c:\Windows\Temp

Comment: @Loonquawl Why should I avoid c:\Windows\Temp? because when I try to use c:\, it doesn't work for the permission problems, but when I used c:\Windows\Temp, it works.

Comment: @Peter Schneider Hi! Thanks for replying, but I should create the xls file and when I search for openxml sdk, they can't create the xls file..is there any way without it?

Comment: @Janes Abou Chleih Thanks for replying. Yea! I tried that already but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Scarlett It's most likely unrelated to the problem, just a bad practice to have hardcoded paths that might not exist. Yes, on your computer it's there, and because it's a default it's there on 99% of Windows computers, but not guaranteed.

You should create a temp file with Path.GetTempFileName(), or if random generated file name is not good then use the directory returned by something like 
Path.GetTempPath() for the user's temp folder 
or 
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP", EnvironmentVariableTarget Machine)
for system temp folder.

Comment: Gotta thanks @Loonquawl !!